# going to new page sets my user_id to null in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have 2 models .. one for User(amitian) and other about
They have a has_one and belongs_to association
Problem is that whenever I create a new about it works fine and set my amitian_id to current_amitian but whenever I go to my new page again.. it updates my amitian_id to NULL

for eg.
this is my sql after I submit the form
insert into about_amitian('values' , amitian_id = 1)
and if i go to new page again it says
update about_amitian set amitian_id = null where about_amitian.id= 1

this is my controller and model

```
class AboutAmitiansController < ApplicationController

  before_action :authenticate_amitian!

  def new
    @amitian = current_amitian
  @about_amitian = @amitian.build_about_amitian
  end

  def create
    @amitian = current_amitian
    @about_amitian = @amitian.create_about_amitian(about_amitian_params)
    if @about_amitian.save
            redirect_to root_url
            flash[:notice] = 'success'
        else
            render root_url
        end
  end


private

    def about_amitian_params
    params.require(:about_amitian).permit(:dob,:interest,:bio,:catch_phrase,:relationship_status)
    end

end
```

and model

```
belongs_to :amitian
```

and in amitian
    has_one :about_amitian

Why is it Updating my database ?

Comment: You don't really have to rebuild `@about_amitian` in every `new` request. If you're always creating and updating the AboutAmitian through the `current_amitian`, that alone will take care of keeping the amitian_id in sync. Try using `@about_amitian = AboutAmitian.new` in your `new` action.

Comment: The flow seems weird, if current_amitian already has an about, why do we create a new one for him ? (u said its a has_one) relationship

Comment: Are you using devise? Than generally current_model_name is globally accessible once model_name is signed in.

Comment: @Joel_Blum yes I have a has_one relation.. if i don't create from current)user then how may I implement this relation in my new function?